# Can I assume incrementing long will never overflow in my lifetime?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

Let's say I'm making a game development engine. It has an object registry that keeps track of when each object was last updated. To do this, I use a long, assigned by a global static class. Something like this:

```
public static class GlobalRegistrar {
    // *** Static data
    private static long m_currentModTag = long.MinValue+1; // Current ModTag value
    public const long ModTagUntagged = long.MinValue;

    public static long GetNextModTag() {
        #if MULTITHREADING
            return Interlocked.Increment(ref m_currentModTag);
        #else
            return ++m_currentModTag;
        #endif
    }
    public static void UpdateModTag(ref long mtag) {
        #if MULTITHREADING
            mtag = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_currentModTag));
        #else
            mtag = ++m_currentModTag;
        #endif
    }
```

And I test for 'up-to-date' with something like:

```
    public bool UpToDate() {
        if (m_updater == null) { return false; }
        foreach(IObj dataObj in m_dependsOn) {
            if (dataObj.MTag > m_mtag) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You can probably fill in the blanks of this code. It's very basic.

Can I safely assume that `m_currentModTag` will never overflow? Since there's around 18 **pentillion** values to increment through?

I mean, I could come up with a way of allowing it to wrap around, and do something clever in the `UpToDate` method, allowing it to detect a likely wrap, but it would take a bit of a performance hit, and it would be uglier.  Do I really need to?

18 pentillion, only by incrementing.  I think I can just assume it will never overflow for the rest of my lifetime.

Comment: `Can I safely assume that m_currentModTag will never overflow?` - no. you can asume that, after enough time, it _will_ overflow. but you can asume that it _practically_ will _most likely_ never overflow. there's just a huge conceptual difference between "never" and "practically never". i think this question is, all in all, moot; and can only lead to opinionated discussions.

Comment: No one else can answer this other than to say "it can overflow" and "it will overflow if you increment it enough". Only your use case will determine the likelihood of it being incremented enough.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann ... that's your opinion. :P
My use case is a Unity extension, so it's a tool for others.  I have no idea how big or crazy their games will be.  I just think on a practical scale it's a safe assumption.  I think I'm testing the waters to see how strong this idea is.  I think I'm hoping no one talks me into implementing wrap-around contingencies...

Comment: If you have an idea of the maximum frequency with which your increment method is called, you can calculate the minimum time until it wraps. Say if you are sure it is never called more often than every Microsecond, it will last at least 600 years until a long wraps.

Comment: If you want to make life easier for the poor guy having to debug this issue when it occurs (and, obviously, if your performance constraints allow for the additional check): Throw an exception with a descriptive error message instead of silently overflowing.

Comment: What is a "pentillion"? Do you perhaps mean "quintillion"? If yes, then it probably depends on how frequently it increments. If the increment happens once per second, then that is ~31.69 billion years, so yes we will probably see the eventual heat death of the universe before it overflows (or other software/hardware limitations are encountered, more likely). But if it increments every nanosecond, then it will overflow in ~18,252 years, so again yes you will be long dead and probably we will not be using that computer anymore.

Comment: But it just goes to show that if you increase the increment frequency to a high enough rate, it could overflow pretty quickly. For example incrementing every femtosecond will overflow in a little over 16 and a half minutes.

Comment: If you need an arbitrary precision use an arbitrary precision type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do some math.

2^64 is about 10^19. Say that a computer can do 10^10 increments per second. There are on the order of 10^7 seconds on a year. So you should have about 100 years before a overflow, give or take a magnitude.

Now you should ask yourself a few questions

- What would the effect of an overflow be? A game and flight controls of an aircraft have very different requirements.
- How long are your program expected to be running? A game will probably not run for more than a few days. Some control software might run uninterrupted for many years.
- How long do you think your software will be used for? Computers in 20 years time might be much faster.

In many cases just assuming no overflow should be fine, but you should only do so after estimating the risk.

Comment: Yeah, there's a famous historical case of a company misjudging your second point: https://www.cnet.com/news/windows-may-crash-after-49-7-days/. It's [apparently related to a 32-bit counter overflowing](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=22701247).